# rewrite rule prevents image file requests

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess file is as follows.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^write$ /write.php [L]
RewriteRule ^write/([^/]*)$ /write.php?bid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*) blog.php?author=$1&title=$2&date=$3
```

The problem is request for an image file is redirected to blog.php file. 
For example request for 
    http://domainname.com/images/10005/Brooklyn-Museum.jpg 
    is redirected to blog.php. how to correct this to access existing static resources properly?

Comment: Just add another condition checking if the request targets the folder `images`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^write/?$ /write.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^write/([^/]+)/?$ /write.php?bid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /blog.php?author=$1&title=$2&date=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. ths worked. may i knw what were the mistakes in my code?

Comment: Yes sure. Problem was that in your code you had `RewriteCond` before your first rule only. `RewriteCond` are only used for the immeidately next `RewriteRule` therefore your image requests were also getting rewritten by the last rule.

Comment: what does this rule RewriteRule ^ - [L] mean?

Comment: That means do nothing if request is for a valid file or directory.